# Iphone "Go" button is redirecting to previous page

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I'm working on a web application which has multiple screens, every screen has 2 submit buttons(1 is the Back button and the other is next button)
like below.

```
 <input name="back" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" type="submit" value="Back" formnovalidate formaction="BackToIncidentInfo?tabId=@Model.TabId">
 <input name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

So when I click on Back button it will redirect to previous page and the next button redirects me to next page. 
This is working fine in web. But when I open this application in Iphone safari browser, and click on `Go button` in Iphone Keyboard, it is redirecting me to the previous page.
This should behave like the `Next` button in the form.

I had this same issue with Android phone too.

Comment: Well, it's the first `type="submit"` button, it seems reasonable that it'd be the default behaviour. Does it have to be a `submit` button…?

Comment: Yes, I've to save the form when I click on Back button, Since I don't want to fire the validations on back button I've formnovalidate attribute to that

Comment: The below solution is working fine... But now I've another requirement: The Next button will be disabled until all mandatory fields are filled, so when I click on GO button when the Next button is disabled it is redirecting me to previous page... but it should not do that instead do nothing... how can I achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rootcause of the issue is, Since the first button which is placed in the form is `Back` and is of `type=submit`,  it seems reasonable that it'd be the default behaviour.
So to fix this issue I changed the order of the buttons by using `order concept in bootstrap 4`.

Below is the fix which worked for me.

```
 <input name="submit" class="order-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next">
 <input name="back" class="order-1 btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" type="submit" value="Back" formnovalidate formaction="BackToIndex?tabId=@Model.TabId">
```